# Profiling java application running as service(locally/remotely)

Tags: java, profiling

I'm looking for a tool which can profile the java application running as a windows service (  remotely/locally either way) .

I've come across **VisualVM** as one option. Are there any other products available other than VisualVm.I'm more interested in reputated product. Can **Jprofiler** do this for me?

**VisualVM** , Does it give class wise list of profiling ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as), if you want to use Java VisualVM. It describes how java application running as a Windows service can be monitored and/or profiled using VisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

JVisualVM is you best shot. It's free, comes with the JVM and gives you a pretty decent range of functionality. Not sure what you mean by "class wise list of profiling." But it will show you where the majority of your execution time is spent.

You can execute jvsiualvm by going to $JAVA_HOME/bin and typing jvisualvm. Then select the the vm you wish to profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BTrace to instrument your application and to measure the parts of the application that you are interested in. BTrace logs its output to files, which you can later or in real-time transfer to a monitoring application, such as EurekaJ (which I've written myself).

Both tools are Open Sourced and free to use. BTrace uses the "GNU Public License v.2 w/Classpath Exception" license, while EurekaJ uses the GPLv3 license.

InfoQ Writeup on the two tool including VisualVM and a few commandline tools: http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source

Answer (score 0):

Link [How can I monitor my Java application running as Windows Service with Visual VM?](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/faq.html#11) says that on recent Windows versions only JMX mode can be used, but not local.